# Get byte[] from MySQL in Json format

Tags: mysql, json, blob, gson

I've been trying for a while to get a byte[] from my database blob and then parse it to json and send it to my clients. I first get the blob from the database and then I get the byte array by doing:

```
MyObject temp = new MyObject()
Blob icon = dbResult.getBlob(1);
temp.setIcon(icon.getBytes(1, (int)icon.length()));
```

Later on I parse MyObject to a json string which I send back to clients. But it seems that the json string becomes pretty much corrupted when parsing the byte[].

An example of how it might look:

```
[{"icon":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCAFQAPwDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHAAAAQUBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgEDBAUGAAcI
```

I parsed this to json in my webservice which is a jersery webservice. When i try to parse it from json into a class object at client side, it throws IllegalStateException(Gson).

Anyone knows what this is about and what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to transfer binary data using json, you better explicitly encode it with [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and then decode it on receiver's side. JSON isn't designed to wrap binaries, so the problems when trying to make this were expectable.

Comment: Okay! You got any idea of how to do this at the jersey webservice, like a code example?

Comment: Do you mean encoding it into a string and decode that string at client side?

Comment: Exactly. Java is able to encode/decode data to/from base64 string.

Comment: Okay so i have been doing this now but there are still problems. The encoded string is still huge - too big for the json, so it gets clipped. The image is just 16kb..

Comment: The client side doesnt get the same as the serverside encoded String, it looks the same until it suddenly ends. Is there any limit size on a json package?

Comment: That's a library-imposed limit. I've seen multiple megs in a single JSON string, as you'd expect, since you can generate it any way you want. Check your library api documentation, check your framework's configuration for a return length limit, and if all else fails, split the string into smaller strings and return them individually to the client. Obviously reassembly is wasteful, but at least it works.

Comment: I noticed that it was the android logcat that was limiting meaning there was nothing wrong with the json from the beginning. But thanks for your input on base64, my images show up fine now :)